# Is there any good comparison of Lego Electric systems?

Tags: electronics

Coming back to Lego after a 20 year break gave me headache when discovering the electric systems available. Is there a good comparison around or could we make one here? What connector fits, what voltages etc. What will my 9V system fit with? Anything compatible with Mindstorms?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/what-are-the-electrical-properties-of-electric-lego-systems It could use some updates to cover Powered Up.

Comment: That looks spot on, wonder why it didn’t show up when searching. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: Guess it need update with power up and the new robot inventor system.

Comment: I've expanded and updated that answer to include Powered Up.

Comment: @jncraton wow great!